Including commercial code in an open source EPL-1.0 project?
I work on an open source project that is licensed using the Eclipse Public License 1.0 (EPL-1.0) and available on GitHub. My project is a dashboard for other developers, not a library.
I found some commercial code that I felt would be useful for the project. I reached out to the company and they were open to licensing the code to my project. They would be providing icons for me to use and an algorithm to select the correct icon. I'm not sure if they would be providing a specific library for the algorithm or if I'd need to actually implement it myself.
Given my project is open source, nothing would stop someone from cloning and rebranding. The commercial company, obviously doesn't want this and is only happy to explicitly license to my project.
So it's not clear to me how I would integrate their code correctly.

Would I just need to include their license?
Would I need to update/change the license of my project?
Is it even possible, or are these projects just incompatible?

I can add links to the specific projects if that is helpful.

Any addition in the form of a seperate module to your open source project (licensed under EPL-1.0) may be licensed independently, including a proprietary license. Therefore, you keep the company code licensed to you closed and keep distributing your source code under the same license.
However, if the additions result in a derivative work, this latter should be licensed under the same license (EPL-1.0), which means the whole source code should be made available.
